# VBA pass UDF instantly like WorksheetFunctions during step-through

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there was a way to pass UDF's instantly instead of "Entering" the function during step-through debugging. I commonly use functions that I know are fully working, and I often don't want to enter each one when I'm debugging. This is even more annoying when you pass multiple functions as arguments and have to enter each one before you get a return.

This question came from me frequently using things such as `Application.WorksheetFunction.functionName` and wanting to create a function that did the same exact thing and would also pass instantly, but with a shorter name.

Is there an option in VBA or perhaps an `Application.Setting` or `Option Setting` that I could use for this? The difficulty here would be that I only want this on some functions, not all..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put a breakpoint after your function as shown below:

[image]

2) Debug using F8 till the line with "myFunction".

3) Press F5 to jump to the breakpoint (by executing the current code).

You can put multiple breakpoints and jump multiple times to the next breakpoint using F5 in your code.

Comment: This does make sense. I typically either do this or just write `stop` after and hit F5 if the next line takes me out of the function. If this is the only resolution then I think that pretty much answers it. The question really came out of laziness and wanting to neither put a break point nor write stop, but to simply F8 my way through portions of the code. Will mark as solved after more time for other suggestions. Thank you